Retrieve ConstraintViolation from ParameterValidationResult when validating QueryParam
Since Spring Framework 6.1.x, HandlerMethodValidationException is thrown when constraint on @RequestParam is violated, and the exception contains ParameterValidationResult.
When validating @RequestParam, ParameterValidationResult only contains DefaultMessageSourceResolvable, and it does not support way to retrieve the original ConstraintViolation which caused the errors.
Is there way to retrieve ConstraintViolation from ParameterValidationResult of HandlerMethodValidationException?

It seems current version of spring mvc does not support this
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/33025

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
